# Not able to install VirtualBox guest addition in Debian 3.16.0-4 guest

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine, guest-additions

I have a Debian (VirtualBox) guest on a Windows 7 host.
   I am trying to install guest additions and I did following steps.

1. "apt-get update"
2. "apt-get upgrade"
3. "apt-get install build-essential module-assistant"
4. "m-a prepare"
5. "mount /media/cdrom0"
6. "cd /media/cdrom0"
7. "sh VBoxLinuxAdditions.run"

   step 7 fails to install guest additions with following messages:

=============================================

```
root@vig-debian:/media/cdrom0# sh VBoxLinuxAdditions.run   
Verifying archive integrity... All good.  
Uncompressing VirtualBox 4.1.14 Guest Additions for Linux.........  
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer  
Removing installed version 4.1.14 of VirtualBox Guest Additions...  
Removing existing VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.  
Removing existing VirtualBox non-DKMS kernel modules ...done.  
Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel modules  
The headers for the current running kernel were not found. If the following  
module compilation fails then this could be the reason.  

Building the main Guest Additions module ...fail!  
(Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong)  
Doing non-kernel setup of the Guest Additions ...done.  
Installing the Window System drivers  
Warning: unknown version of the X Window System installed.  Not installing  
X Window System drivers.  
Installing modules ...done.  
Installing graphics libraries and desktop services components ...done.  
root@vig-debian:/media/cdrom0#
```

error says "The headers for the current running kernel were not found"
Below is my kernel version and headers, which I think is fine.

```
root@vig-debian:/media/cdrom0# uname -a  
Linux vig-debian 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2 (2016-04-08)   x86_64 GNU/Linux  
root@vig-debian:/media/cdrom0# cd /usr/src/  
root@vig-debian:/usr/src# ls  
linux                 linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common  vboxguest-4.1.14  
linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64  linux-kbuild-3.16  
root@vig-debian:/usr/src#
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not fine, more precisely: not enough.

```
apt install linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64
```

Comment: tried it, still same issue (same error when tried to install guest addition)

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: unknown version of the X Window System installed.  Not installing
>   X Window System drivers.

Some packages need to be installed on your system:

```
apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11 xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core
```